# Accesing ASANA data using python requests

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, asana, asana-api

First of all, I'm not a Python guru as you can probably tell... So here we go.

I'm trying to use Asana's API to pull data with Python requests (Projects, tasks, etc) and doing the authentication using Oauth 2.0... I've been trying to find a simple python script to have something to begin with but I haven't had any luck and I can't find a decent and simple example!

I already created the app and got my client_secret and client_secret. But I don't really know where or how to start... Could anybody help me please?

```
import sys, os, requests

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

import asana
import json
from six import print_
import requests_oauthlib
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client_id=os.environ['ASANA_CLIENT_ID'],
client_secret=os.environ['ASANA_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        # this special redirect URI will prompt the user to copy/paste the code.
        # useful for command line scripts and other non-web apps
redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

if 'ASANA_CLIENT_ID' in os.environ:

    #Creates a client with previously obtained Oauth credentials#
    client = asana.Client.oauth(

        #Asana Client ID and Secret, set as a Windows environments to avoid hardcoding variables into the script#
        client_id=os.environ['ASANA_CLIENT_ID'],
        client_secret=os.environ['ASANA_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        # this special redirect URI will prompt the user to copy/paste the code.
        # useful for command line scripts and other non-web apps
        redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
        )
    print ("authorized=", client.session.authorized)

    # get an authorization URL:

    (url, state) = client.session.authorization_url()


    try:
        # in a web app you'd redirect the user to this URL when they take action to
        # login with Asana or connect their account to Asana
        import webbrowser
        webbrowser.open(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print_("Open the following URL in a browser to authorize:")
        print_(url)

    print_("Copy and paste the returned code from the browser and press enter:")

    code = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    # exchange the code for a bearer token
    token = client.session.fetch_token(code=code)

    #print_("token=", json.dumps(token))
    print_("authorized=", client.session.authorized)

me = client.users.me()


print "Hello " + me['name'] + "\n"

params = {'client_id' : client_id, 'redirect_uri' : redirect_uri, 'response_type' : token,}

print_("*************** Request begings *******************"+"\n")
print_("r = requests.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me)" + "\n")
r = requests.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me', params)

print_(r)
print_(r.json)
print_(r.encoding)

workspace_id = me['workspaces'][0]['id']
print_("My workspace ID is" + "\n")
print_(workspace_id)

print_(client.options)
```

I'm not sure how to use the requests lib with Asana. Their python doc did not help me. I'm trying to pull the available projects and their code colours so I can later plot them into a web browser (For a high-level view of the different projects and their respective colours - Green, yellow or red)

When I introduce the url (https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me) into a browser, it gives me back a json response with the data, but when I try to do the same with the script, it gives me back a 401 (not authorized) response.

Does anybody know what I'm missing / doing wrong?

Thank you!!!

Comment: I see you using the asana oauth library. But not OAuth2Session from requests-oauthlib library. I think you should follow the example given here instead - https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#backend-application-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the Requests library is a lower level library.  You would need to pass all of the parameters to your requests.

Is there a reason you are not exclusively using the Asana Python client library to make requests?  All of the data you are looking to fetch from Asana (projects, tasks, etc.) are accessible using the Asana Python library.  You will want to look in the library to find the methods you need.  For example, the methods for the `tasks` resource [can be found here](https://github.com/Asana/python-asana/blob/master/asana/resources/gen/tasks.py).  I think this approach will be easier (and less error-prone) than switching between the Asana lib and the Requests lib. The Asana lib is actually built on top of Requests ([as seen here](https://github.com/Asana/python-asana/blob/master/asana/client.py#L56)).

Comment: Thanks for the links provided. They did help a lot! Cheers.